# How to compare the values of 2 JSONS?

Tags: java, json, jackson

How do I compare whether the values are lesser than or equal between 2 jsons?

I have a Json :

```
{"item1":{"443189342":0,"438702562":5,"437211162":0,"496545602":0,"444776102":0},"item2":{"443189342":4,"438702562":2,"437211162":2,"496545602":5,"444776102":22}}
```

As for now I am doing :

```
  private static void compareValues(ObjectNode value1, ObjectNode value2) {
        assertEquals(value1, value2);
    }
```

But I would like to assert if the values are off threshold (0.05) ? I mean how do I verify whether the values are same or value1 lesser than value2 ?

Comment: Well, simply you would need to add your own logic to compare the json!

Answer (score 0):

First copy pasta some json into 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
This will give you a nice java class for the object!
Then You want to extend Comparable in that class. This will require you to override the compartor.  See link below.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-override-compareto-method-in.html
 Good luck man!!